# What happened to FindSDL2 in CMake?

Tags: cmake, sdl-2

I use SDL2 in my game. I always was using custom FindSDL2.cmake, because there is no one in standard CMake set. However, some time ago posts about FindSDL2 did appeared. Example: [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/8vgba5/using_sdl_with_cmake/e1n81fj).

> If your cmake is new enough and it has FindSDL2.cmake file, you can do this:

```
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
```

But when I download latest CMake (3.13.2), it doesn't include `FindSDL2.cmake`.

What happened to it?

Comment: Can you show use your CMakeLists.txt?
FindSDL2 is found in cmake 3.12.1 at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FindSDL2 has never appeared in CMake.
Following the reject reason in [pull request #149](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/pull/149), SDL2 ships with a `SDL2Config.cmake`, which provides a [cmake package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-packages.7.html).
The documentation for [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_package.html) states that `find_package(SDL2)` will behave as follows:

- Look for `FindSDL2.cmake`, use that if it exists. (module mode)
- Otherwise, use the information in `SDL2Config.cmake` or `sdl2-config.cmake`. (config mode)

In short, make sure that your SDL2 package has installed the `SDL2Config.cmake` file and that is on your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. The documentation lists the exact paths and prefixes it looks under.

Once you managed to `find_package(SDL2)`, the following targets are available for use in `target_link_libraries`:

```
SDL2::SDL2main
SDL2::SDL2
SDL2::SDL2-static
```

Comment: In my Ubuntu I can only find `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SDL2/sdl2-config.cmake`.

Comment: From the documentation:
Given the name Foo, it looks for a file called `FooConfig.cmake` or `foo-config.cmake`. I added the second form to the answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

To easily integrate the SDL2 library, I developed [cross-platform modern CMake modules](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules) for finding and using the SDL2 library as well as other related libraries:

- SDL2: [example](https://github.com/aminosbh/basic-c-sdl-project), [game example](https://github.com/aminosbh/basic-c-sdl-game)
- SDL2_image: [example](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-image-sample)
- SDL2_ttf: [example](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-ttf-sample)
- SDL2_mixer: [example](https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-mixer-sample)
- SDL2_net
- SDL2_gfx: [animation example](https://github.com/aminosbh/flying-plane-sdl-animation)

So the only things that you should do in order to integrate the SDL2 library are:

1. Clone SDL2 CMake modules inside your project:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-cmake-modules cmake/sdl2
```

2. Add the following lines in your main `CMakeLists.txt`

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/sdl2)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2::Main)
```

**Note:** If CMake didn't find the SDL2 library (in Windows), we can specify the CMake option `SDL2_PATH` as follows:

```sh
cmake .. -DSDL2_PATH="/path/to/sdl2"
```

For more details, please read the README.md file.
This is a list of SDL2 samples and projects: https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl-samples-and-projects

Comment: Apologises for asking here but your github and stackoverflow do not have PMs to message directly.

Having issues setting the path for SDL2

`
    -DSDL2_PATH=C:\Library\SDL2

    -- Could NOT find . (missing: SDL2_LIBRARY) (found version "2.0.12")
    -- Found SDL2main: C:/Library/SDL2/lib/libSDL2main.a (found version "2.0.12") 
`

Comment: The repo is updated 4 years ago, do they still work with latest SDL2 version?